# Can we use Ruby gems in our Rhomobile (rhode) application?

Tags: rhodes, rhomobile

Is it possible to use Ruby gems (like `authlogic`, `devise`) in our Rhomobile application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There are different ways you can include external libraries, including RubyGems and custom extensions.  Please refer to the link below for information.

http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/extensions

Comment: If this pointed you in the right direction, please mark this as the correct answer.  If not, let me know if you'd like clarification. Thanks!